# BASH date addition//subtraction in days - wrong syntax

Tags: linux, bash, date

Quick question hopefully.  I'm still getting used to the BASH short form and I'm doing something really stupid with syntax and I'm just not seeing it.  So any help would be appreciated.

Basically I'm pulling info from Hive over a 12 month period, but due to the table size I need to pull data a few days at time, e.g. 7 days.  The only issue is because the number of days may not divide equally into a year the last loop cycle will need to determine how many days are left.  I'm trying to make this check  within each cycle by: -

```
If (end date – start date) in days < 7 days then
    query end date = query start date + (end date – start date) in days
else
    query end date = query start date + 7 days
```

The query start date initially starts at 12 months ago and then is incremented within each loop cycle by the 7 days or whatever days are left going by the statements above.

As mentioned I'm getting my syntax wrong with date addition/subtraction.  The error message I'm getting is simple "Incorrect syntax" although I would really expect anything else.  As I understand it BASH does not have any simple function to subtract one date from another to get the number of days or am I mistaken?  Do you mind having a quick look at this and pointing out what I'm doing wrong?  Issues are the end date on the echo and more importantly the IF statement.

```
#Set dates dynamically
DT_START=$(date -d "-12 month -$(($(date +%-d)-1)) day" +%s)
DT_END=$(date -d "+1 days -$(($(date +%-d)-1)) day" +%s)
I_DAYS=7

#loop per set number of days with the 12 month period and insert into table
echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S): Last 12 month period is $(date -d"@${DT_START}" '+%Y-%m-%d') to $(date -d"-1 days @${DT_END}" '+%Y-%m-%d')";

while [ ${DT_START} -lt ${DT_END} ]; do
    #increment date by either the set number of days or whatever days are left on the last increment
    #date in string format for query range
    DT_STR=$(date -d"@${DT_START}" +%Y-%m-%d)
    if [ $(((${DT_END} - ${DT_START}) + 43200) / 86400) days -lt ${I_DAYS} ]; then
        DT_STR_NEXT=$(date -d"${DT_STR}+$(( ((${DT_END}-${DT_START})+43200)/86400 )) days" +%Y-%m-%d);
    else
        DT_STR_NEXT=$(date -d"${DT_STR}+${I_DAYS} days" +%Y-%m-%d);
    fi

    hive_exec "
        insert into table test
        select col1, col2, col3
        from foo
        where actual_date >= '${DT_STR}'
        and actual_date < '${DT_STR_NEXT}'";

    DT_START=$(date -d"${DT_STR_NEXT}" +%s) #increment date for next loop
done
```

Comment: FYI, all-caps names are conventional for environment variables and builtins, not shell-local variables as used here.

Comment: Anyhow -- the place to start debugging is `set -x`, to see the actual commands run by the script, and perhaps `set -e`, to terminate execution at the first failure.

Comment: By the way -- big code dumps aren't exceptionally welcome here -- in general, we ask that code samples be reduced to the smallest, most self-contained thing necessary to represent a given (very specific) problem. This also means that each question should have one, and only one, specific error rather than showcasing code with several problems. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax error is coming from the line

```
if [ $(((${DT_END} - ${DT_START}) + 43200) / 86400) days -lt ${I_DAYS} ]; then
```

...because `days` is not valid as part of a `test` expression. Since your intent is not clear, it's hard to say how best to improve this line.

Since your shell is bash, by the way, you can write this with much more natural math-context syntax (letting you use `<` rather than `-lt` and elide expansion operators in most cases):

```
if (( ( ( DT_END - DT_START + 43200 ) / 86400 ) < I_DAYS )); then
```

---

That said, you have other errors earlier, leading up to that. Running your script with `bash -x`, you'll see something like the following:

```
++ date '-d-1 days @1414890352' +%Y-%m-%d
date: invalid date `-1 days @1414890352'
```

...corresponding with a usage error for `date` on line 9. In general, using `set -x` is a good idea when debugging.

Comment: @Darybrain, something like `echo "...$(date -d "$(date -d '@1414890352' +%Y-%m-%d) - 1 day")..."`